# Getting the wrong number when converting from byte[] to int

Tags: java, arrays, endianness

I am trying to convert an int to a byte[] and back again, but I think I am doing something wrong along the way. My code is basically:

```
byte[] array = new byte[4];
array[3] = (byte) ( num & 0xFF);   
array[2] = (byte) ((num >> 8) & 0xFF);   
array[1] = (byte) ((num >> 16) & 0xFF);   
array[0] = (byte) ((num >> 24) & 0xFF);
```

And:

```
for (int i =0; i < 4; i++) {
    num = (num << 8) + (array[i] & 0xff);
}
```

If I start off with the number 72, for example, after converting it to a byte array and back I get the number 795108710. Am I missing a step, or are maybe my endians mixed up? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried using the opposite edian?

Comment: Are you initializing `num` to `0` before you start?

Comment: When I use the opposite endian, the number I get is 1717920815. I am initializing num to 0 before I start.

Comment: You have not allowed for the sign of int. Extract the sign. Then make the number absolute

Comment: Your two code snippets do not match; you're filling `array` but reading from `buffer`. What does `array` contain after filling it, what are the values in it? If they make sense, it is the 2nd snippet that has the problem.

Comment: I tried to compile the snipplet you posted here, with `int num = 72` before the conversion to `byte[]` and `byte[] buffer = array; int currentPosition = 0; num = 0` before the conversion back to `int`. Everything worked fine, your problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Edit: cleaned up code snippets. @nd, you might be right. I've tried using the ByteBuffer method and still am not getting the correct results, so I think the problem might be elsewhere in my code :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ByteBuffer`; it contains methods to encode many different data types without the need to worry about endian and the like:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
bb.putInt(index, 72);
...

int value = bb.getInt(index);
```

Comment: +1: You can change the ByteOrder with `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array[3]=(byte)(num & 0xFF);
array[2]=(byte)(num & 0x0000FF00);
array[1]=(byte)(num & 0x00FF0000);
array[0]=(byte)(num & 0xFF000000);
```

To get it back:

```
num=(int)(array[0]&0xFF) | (int)(array[1]&0xFF) | (int)(array[2]&0xFF) | (int)(array[3]&0xFF);
```

Or try a loop if you want:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
 num=num+(int)(array[i]&0xFF);
}
```

This one is in C#. Not sure if it would work on Java. But I think, will do.